# Django rest framewor deal with many=True serializer data to list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I get data like this.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "fields": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "att1"},
        {"id": 2, "name": "att2"}
    ]
}
```

And I need fields without keys like `fields: ["att1", "att2"]`.

I could use SerializerMethod do this. Is there some method like `source='form.fields.name'`?

`CharField(source='form.fields.name')` not work with many=True objects.

Code:

```py
class EavForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class EavAttribute(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(EavForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='fields')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class EavAttributeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EavAttribute
        fields = '__all__'


class EavFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields = EavAttributeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EavForm
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have a EavValue object related_to EavForm. How get fields like `eav_value_obj.fields` as a list?

```py
class EavValue(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(EavForm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='values')
    fields = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='form.fields.name' # not work like this. 
    )
```

Comment: Why are you defining a serializer field on your `EavValue` model class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class EavFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fields = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='name'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = EavForm
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Thanks, but can I use another object related to Eavform  in the real environment, something not work when I use `form.fields.name`.